# Why does Hollywood rarely hire well-known voice-actors/actresses instead of well-known actors/actresses to voice-act animations?

Tags: animation, american-cinema, voice-acting

There are many voice-actors who are just voice-actors and they are very experienced and talented in it with so many types of voices they can produce (such as old voice-actors like Tara Strong, Jim Cummings, etc. and some newer talented voice actors.)

Why is Hollywood ignoring the opportunity to hire these persons for their animation projects? Why is it insisting on working with non-voice-actor actors who can't produce so many types of voices and just speak in animations with their regular tones?

Comment: What makes you believe well known voice actors are not getting hired for animations? What examples do you have that confirm that? where would John DiMaggio and Roger Craig Smith fit, for example? They both have ongoing voice work for animation.

Comment: just take a brief look at Hollywood animations from the last decade. at least the top 5 casts were well-known actors/actresses.

Comment: I'm seeing a ton of really weird and confusing edits on this thing. Maybe take some time and really think about *if*, how and in which way you want to edit this question and what it is you want to express. Especially the constant referral to some mythical "before" is quite confusing. *When* would that "before" have been and before what was it?

Comment: You also see respectable actors doing other, less-famous VO work. Here's *[Britain's Biggest Warship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s4OmngvGuw)*, a perfectly ordinary UK reality TV show, but voiced by British A-list actress Caroline Katz of *Doc Martin* fame.  Obviously the producers wanted to bring that quality vibe.

Comment: @Luciano just came back to this and found a missing information. The well-known voice-actors/actresses are mostly hired for dubbing foreign movies, TV series, and animations. Animations which are produced inside of the USA are mostly voice-acted by famous celebrities.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because movie making is a business and having well known actors and other celebrities voice characters helps sell the movie.

I'm sure Hollywood would prefer to hire less expensive talent for all their movies, but they calculate that better known names are worth the additional cost.

The calculation shifts for animated TV content, from needing to cover 90-180 minutes, to perhaps 20 30-minute shows per season. Here a well known name may not be able to commit to this duration or the cost would be prohibitive for the return.

Comment: I'm not so sure about TV content. Aaron Paul on BoJack Horseman or Sarah Chalke on Rick and Morty would eg be examples of well-known actors doing voice-acting on TV (as regulars).

Comment: @tim: Bojack is an allround exception here ([cast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3398228/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)), but just because an exception exist doesn't mean that the general tendency described in this answer is wrong. Also, Sarah Chalke is an iffy comparison - [she's equal parts voice actress and actress](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0149950/) and I wouldn't particularly list her as an A-list movie/TV celebrity (I had to look up who she is though she is a familar guest star face)

Comment: @tim - well, I've never heard of that woman, and I had to google the guy before I said "aaah the Breaking Bad guy", so they can't be that well known.

Comment: @iandotkelly Are voice-actors OK with that?

Comment: @aminabzz ... you're asking whether they are happy to be paid less for doing the same job as someone else?  I'm sure they would prefer to be better rewarded for their work, but I am also sure they understand why this is.